# How to attach a shimano crank arm power meter on a low end bike with a square taper crankset?

Tags: crankset

I have an old bike that has a cheap square taper crankset.

[image]

And I would like to attach a crank arm power meter to it that will fit a Shimano crankset.

[image]

Is there an adapter that can fit into the square hole and offer grips for the Shimano crank to hold onto or do I have to buy something like a Tiagra or Sora crankset and fit that to my bike? (the crankset would be worth more than the bike at that point haha)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crank power meter incompatible with my bottom bracket](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/59245/crank-power-meter-incompatible-with-my-bottom-bracket)

Answer (score 7):

Are you able to replace the entire existing square taper bottom bracket with a compatible cartridge with the same splined fitting?  This assumes you bought the power meter already. Of course you need both crank arms even if just one side has a power meter.

The other option is to get a pedal-based power meter instead of a crank-based one.

Comment: A pedal based PWR meter would also be transferable between different bicycles in a matter of minutes with a simple pedal wrench.